# How can I use context on my functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I was using context without a problem in my regular components like this:

```
import { LanguageContext } from "./languageContext";


export class Jobs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
.
.
.
{this.context.main.title}
.
.
.


Jobs.contextType = LanguageContext;
```

However, when it came to my functional component, this threw me an error

"Cannot read property context of undefined"

```
import { LanguageContext } from "./languageContext";

function StripeButton() {
...
StripeButton.contextType = LanguageContext;

...
{this.context.main.title}
...
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: have you tried `context.main.title` without `this`?

Comment: just did! says "context is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a contextType in your functional component. To use Context in functional component, you need to make use of `useContext` hook which is available in v16.8.0 or above of react

```
import { LanguageContext } from "./languageContext";

function StripeButton() {
    const context = useContext(LanguageContext);
    ...
      {context.main.title}
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this but it did not work. I keep getting "useContext is not defined". I updated my react version to v16.8.0. What am I missing?

Comment: I solved it and now I get "useContext is not a function"

Comment: Did you update your react-dom version version to 16.8.0 as well

Comment: Are you using `context.main.title` instead of `this.context.main.title`

Comment: nope that was a mistake, I am using this.context.main.title